# Delete entities, processes, dashboard and reports from managed solutions

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-2016

My requirement is to delete certain entities, processes, dashboards and reports from managed solutions on a CRM dynamics 365 system (TEST, UAT, PROD).
The changes must first be implemented in a (Development) CRM Dynamics 365 environment which has Unmanaged solutions.

This is the process we are following:
Developer customizes DEV solutions (unmanaged) and exports solutions as Managed solutions to TEST for QA review:
Unmanaged Solutions (DEV) --Export the Managed Solutions--> TEST CRM Dynamics 365 system
After QA has passed the TEST review:
Unmanaged Solutions (DEV) --Export the Managed Solutions--> UAT CRM Dynamics 365 system
After client has passed UAT review:
Unmanaged Solutions (DEV) --Export the Managed Solutions --> PROD CRM Dynamics 365 system

Note: There are multiple solutions in the environment.  Example : DEV, TEST, UAT and Prod have Solution 1, Solution 2, Solution 3, Solution 4, Solution 5

*How do I **delete Entities, Entities (with dependencies), processes(Workflows), dashboards and reports in DEV from the unmanaged solutions so that it gets deleted from the managed solutions when I export** the solutions into the above TEST, UAT and PROD CRM Dynamics 365 environments?*

Comment: Are you trying to delete all the elements of the managed solutions in all 4 systems? or are you trying to delete just certain parts?

Comment: Certain entities and their dependencies. All entities are not included in the same unmanaged solutions currently. And all dependencies of those entities may not be in all the unmanaged solutions. And these need to be deleted in the SYS, UAT and PROD managed environments.

Answer (score 0):

You can add and change existing configuration settings via a solution, but solutions cannot be used to delete components in a target (TEST, UAT, PROD) environment. If you have a managed solution in UAT or PROD, and you delete it, then it will delete all the elements from that environment.

Answer (score 0):

this modules can not be delete from TEST, UAT and PROD because there are no suggested way to remove modules from a managed solution!

but you can do this with help from SQL (if your crm is on-permise and access to it), in table of solution by change managed field to zero you can export the solution, after this remove all unused componnents from solution xml file (in solution zip file) and import this to CRM again.

after this you can update solution normaly with exported file from DEV.

i do this way in past but I do not justify if you are not an expert in this field!

best regard.